# Ansible: how to parse XML values from URI (REST) xml output

Tags: python, regex, xml, ansible, xml-parsing

i have below Ansible playbook to access my server and fetch data using REST API mechanism, and i am able to get output XML format, but struggling to parse only specific values from that output.

`Ansible Playbook - debug`

```
- debug:
    var: steering

- debug: msg="{{ steering | regex_findall('<name>(.*?)</name>') }}"

- debug: msg="{{ steering | regex_findall('<value>(.*?)</value>') }}"
```

`Output of last 2 debug responses`

```
TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "ip-address",
        "start-port",
        "end-port",
        "realm-id",
    ]
}

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "10.10.10.12",
        "7000",
        "15000",
        "Core",
```

How can i fetch only `name & values` together instead of separate debug responses (by modifying regex_findall).. or else please help if there is any possibility to merge last debug responses to get `name & values` together.

`Expected Output`

```
"ip-address - 10.10.10.12",
"start-port - 7000",
"end-port - 15000",
"realm-id - Core"
```

Please help..

thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't try to tighten a bolt with a screwdriver: use the correct tool. In this case you have e.g. the [`xml` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/xml_module.html)

Comment: Hi Zeitounator, thanks for response.. i have seen `xml module` page, But not found helpful information about getting values from XML response.

Comment: Really ? I'm sure you overlooked the `xmlstring` parameter for the module.