# Ansible: how to filter using varible

Tags: ansible

i have ansible-playbook that gives list of lines in `debug` output.
I am able to filter debug OUTPUT using a `string` (exp: CUST) but I am struggling to filter the list using a variable.

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ List.msg | select('match', '^(CUST)[0-9]+') | list }}"
```

`List msg output:`

```
CUST1
CUST2
NEW1
NEW2
```

from the above debug command, i get CUST1, CUST2 in filtered output.

```
- set_fact:
    filter: "{{ fileout.results[0].content }}"
```

above `filter` generates "CUST" and i want to use this `filter` variable in above debug command.

using below syntax i get nothing, may be ansible is NOT taking it as appropriate variable.

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ List.msg | select('match', '^("{{ filter }}")[0-9]+') | list }}"
```

Please help.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to isolate the declaration of the regex `filter` and simplify the quotation. For example

```
  vars:
    List:
      msg: ['CUST1','CUST2','NEW1','NEW2']
    Patterns: ['CUST','NEW']

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ List.msg | select('match', filter) | list }}"
      vars:
        filter: '^{{ item }}[0-9]+'
      loop: "{{ Patterns }}"
```

gives

```
    "msg": [
        "CUST1", 
        "CUST2"
    ]

    "msg": [
        "NEW1", 
        "NEW2"
    ]
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir, Thanks a lot for your help.. above solution worked perfectly.. Only change i have made is using Pattern as list .. `loop: "{{ [ Patterns ] }}` .. This is because in my task, filter parameter is a dynamic value, it could be CUST or anything.. So i have defined `Patterns` in `vars_prompt`.

Comment: `  vars_prompt:`
`    - name: Patterns`
`      prompt: "Please type input:"`
`      private: no`

Comment: Infact, my original idea is to get the parameters like in below question. But i failed to resolve it and hence i changed my filtering method like this..  
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60023625/ansible-how-to-parse-xml-values-from-uri-rest-xml-output>`